# YouTube video bitstream URLs available only over HTTP

Tags: youtube-api

I have a https secure page https://apps.iacampaigns.co.in/test.html over which i have embedded a youtube video iframe.

The call to this iframe is made over https but there after calls like `//r1---sn-n2xjug5oxu-qxae.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?algorithm=throttle` are made over http.

Therefore now my page has mixed content and it becomes not totally secure.
I checked and found http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/02/https-support-for-youtube-embeds.html.

This confirms that till FEB 2011 although youtube had moved to https parts like video bitstream were still available only over http. 
I would like to know the current status of this.

Are the video bit stream urls still available over http only?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the current state. We understand the need but don't have anything to share at this time

Comment: Are there any updates on this? I am noticing that as of Feb '14 sometimes content can be streamed over HTTPS, but cannot discern what controls this.